# How to select a field inside an array inside an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of object like this :

[image]

I need to select only the array which has coreSystemID = 'T24' so I tried `credsArr.find()` it shows my `.find` is not a function.

below is my code:

```
var creds = credsArr.find(x => x.coreSystemID === 'T24')
```

And I should use the index value like this  - *credsArr[3053]*, because the index may vary so I need to select the array which has coreSystemID = 'T24'

Comment: `credsArr` is an object, not an array, the same for its values, 3052 and 3053...

Comment: If you don't need the key (3053): `Object.values(credsArr).find(cred => cred.coreSystemID === "T24")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let keys = Oject.keys(credsArr).filter(key => credsArr[key].coreSystemID==='T24')
```

keys will have all the keys of credsArr having credsArr[key].coreSystemID as 'T24'

`let systemT24 = credsArr[keys[0]]` will give you the object you are looking for given that there is only one object with coreSystemID as 'T24'.

If you have multiple objects that might have coreSystemID as 'T24' you can map it to a new array  like this:

```
let systemT24 = keys.map(key => credsArr[key])
```

Comment: i'm gettign output as like this - 0: "3053"... Can you assist by selecting the all element in this array "3053"?

Comment: @Mar1009 Check out the modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.values(credsArr):

```
 var creds = Object.values(credsArr).find(x => x.coreSystemID === 'T24');
```

or if you need key of the object:

```
var creds = Object.entries(credsArr).find(x => x[1].coreSystemID === 'T24');
let key = creds[0];
let value = creds[1];
```

Comment: it says  Object.values is not a function  is not a function